# Не работает атрибут "fetch_user"

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Когда я использую данный код, то у меня всё работает

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True, administrator=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: int, *, reason='Нарушение правил'):
    try:
        user = await bot.fetch_user(member)
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(title='Разбан', description=f'Администратор {ctx.author.mention} разбанил пользователя {user.mention}, за {reason}!', color=0x74ff00), delete_after=10)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    except disnake.errors.NotFound:
        await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(title='Ошибка :x:', description=f'У данного пользователя нет блокировки!', color=0xff0000), delete_after=10)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        time.process_time()
```

Но когда я его преобразую для когов

```
@commands.command() #pass_context = True
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True, administrator=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, member: int, *, reason='Нарушение правил'):
        try:
            user = await commands.fetch_user(member)
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(title='Разбан', description=f'Администратор {ctx.author.mention} разбанил пользователя {user.mention}, за {reason}!', color=0x74ff00), delete_after=10)
            await ctx.message.delete()
        except disnake.errors.NotFound:
            await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(title='Ошибка :x:', description=f'У данного пользователя нет блокировки!', color=0xff0000), delete_after=10)
            await ctx.message.delete()
            time.process_time()
```

То у мне выдаёт ошибку

```
AttributeError: module 'disnake.ext.commands' has no attribute 'fetch_user'
```